# Mint 17 with Gigabyte motherboard: no audio from rear audio port

Tags: audio, motherboard, linux-mint, speakers

I just installed Mint 17.  I'm having an issue getting audio from the rear audio port.  When I plug either my headphones or speakers into the front port on the case, the audio works fine, but when I plug it into the rear port connected directly to the mobo, I get no sound.

I'm using a GIGABYTE Z97X-UD5H motherboard.  Everything works fine in my windows partition.

**EDIT:** I realized 2 things:

1. plugging into the front jack does produce sound, but there is a lot of noise.  If I just sit and listen to the sound it's fine, but if I move the mouse, type, or click, there is static.
2. If I plug into the orange jack in the rear, I get the same kind of sound.  It works, but it's staticy.